# 'Sub or function not defined' in UDF. The function is complex( , )

Tags: compilation, user-defined-functions

My goal is to create a UDF which accepts multiple real values and returns a complex one. The code has no problem executing a `sin( )` function (put in as a test to see if standard excel functions are recognized) but has the problem "Compile Error: Sub or function is not defined" with `complex( , )`. Can you help me create such a function?

```vb
Function fctr(w As Double, a As Double, b As Double)
    fctr = Sin(2)
    fctr = Complex(a, b) 'ImDiv(Complex(a, b), ImSum(Complex(0, w), Complex(a, b)))
End Function
```

I expected the function to execute the standard excel function `complex( , )`. To test if there is a problem with standard excel functions, I confirmed that there is not by executing the `sin( )` function.